# Combine multiple text injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has these records on SQL Server

```
RepID   iBegin    iEnd    RepText
1       10        17      This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ... 
1       38        44      This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ... 
1       77        82      This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ... 
2       21        24      ... flights to USA will be...weather temp is 73 degrees ...
2       82        82      ... flights to USA will be...weather temp is 73 degrees ...
```

this table has a text (HTML) and I need to highlight the text that is in between **iBegin **and** iEnd** by adding the `<red>` before and after the highlighted text

I did that on the row level

```
SELECT RepID, RepText, SUBSTRING(RepText,0, iBegin) + '<red>' + SUBSTRING(RepText,iBegin, iEnd-iBegin + 1) + '<\red>' + SUBSTRING(RepText, iEnd, Len(RepText)-iEnd + 1)
FROM table
```

but could not do that with group by so all highlights show in a single record like this

```
RepID    RepText
1          This is a <red>profile</red> of ... Moreover <red>Toyota</red> has been ... such as <red>Mazda</red> also ... 
2          ... flights to <red>USA</red> will be...weather temp is <red>73</red> degrees ...
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why are you doing text-processing in SQL? Why can't you do it in application code?

Comment: And `<red>` is not HTML...

Comment: @Dai because there is no application, it is just this task. and <red> will be replaced with another code. it was used so you can understand the request

Comment: What does `GROUP BY` have to do with anything here? Show us your full query and an expected sample result.

Comment: How do you intend to handle conflicting or overlapping transformations? e.g. `{ RepId: 1, Begin: 1, End: 10 }, { RepId: 1, Begin: 5, End: 12 }`?

Comment: @Dai the query is in there, that what i managed to build and the expected results also in the question.!

Comment: Your query doesn't show you using `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Dai there will be no conflicts

Comment: @Dai i could not build the query with group by the RepText will be wrong. so I just did it for every single row, need a help to make it with group by

Comment: @DaleK string_agg dies not give the intrended results. the RepText will be repeated N times

Comment: @DaleK the RepText will be duplicated something like this "This is a <red>profile</red> of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also.... This is a profile of ... Moreover <red>Toyota</red> has been ... such as Mazda alo.... This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota  has been ... such as <red>Mazda</red> also"

Comment: Given the input data I don't see how you could do this in a set-based fashion in SQL server - the string offsets will change as you process each string substitution. This leads to horrible iterative/cursor based solutions, which is why it's something you'd normally do in the application layer.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've just sketched-out a way to do this by using a scalar UDF with TVPs to pass the set of text-ranges. So it's certainly possible.

Comment: @Dai so you're iterating over the iBegin values in descending order inside a scalar UDF? Iteration is still iteration.

Comment: I guess you could do something with `cross apply`, but it's still an iterative solution. I do recall, however, someone posting a UDF that outputs chunks of texts based on Jeff Moden's string splitter from way back when, so perhaps there is a way to do this kind of thing using a tally table and not an iterative process - however I don't really have the time to try it now.

Comment: The trick for this kind of stuff is to start from the last to the first. Then indexes will not be moving around.

Comment: Or working from first to last while passing along an index offset calculated from the prior offset, if any, and the lengths of the inserted HTML bits, e.g. using a CTE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL Server and whether such string processing is best done in the database...

```
with data as (
    select RepID, iBegin + 1 as iBegin, iEnd + 1 as iEnd, RepText, /* adjust to 1-based index */
        1 + lag(iEnd, 1, 0) over (partition by RepID order by iBegin) as prevBegin,
        1 + max(iEnd) over (partition by RepID) as lastBegin 
    from T
)
select RepID,
    string_agg(
        concat(
            substring(RepText, prevBegin, iBegin - prevBegin),
            '<red>',
            substring(RepText, iBegin, iEnd - iBegin),
            '</red>'
        ), ''
    ) within group (order by iBegin)
    + substring(min(RepText), min(lastBegin), 1000)
from data
group by RepID;
```

This handles each wrapped segment with the non-wrapped segment just before it (via `lag()`) in pairs. Each of those must then be concatenated in proper order along with the final segment at the end. This does assume no overlap in your offsets but that's pretty much a given anyway.

https://dbfiddle.uk/n2beW4E0

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if your `iBegin` and `iEnd` are correct...
Here's a way to do it with a `UDF` and `GROUP BY`:

First the `UDF`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Repl(@text nvarchar(max), @words nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @pre nvarchar(max) = '';
    SET @words = @words + ';';

    WHILE LEN(@words) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @pre = LEFT(@words, CHARINDEX(';', @words) - 1);
            SET @text = REPLACE(@text, @pre, ' <red>' + SUBSTRING(@pre, 2, LEN(@pre) - 1) + '<\red> ');
            SET @words = REPLACE(@words, @pre + ';', '');
        END
    RETURN @text
 END;
```

Then the call would be

```
WITH pre AS
(
    SELECT 
            RepID,
            RepText,
            STRING_AGG(' ' + SUBSTRING(RepText, iBegin + 1, iEnd - iBegin) + ' ', ';') AS Words
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY RepID, RepText
)

SELECT
        RepID,
        dbo.Repl(RepText, Words) AS RepText
FROM pre;
```

And if your data looks like this, you would get your expected output:

```
CREATE TABLE [table]
(
    RepID int,
    iBegin int,
    iEnd int,
    RepText nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO [table]
VALUES
    (1, 10, 17, 'This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ...'),
    (1, 34, 40, 'This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ...'),
    (1, 62, 67, 'This is a profile of ... Moreover Toyota has been ... such as Mazda also ...'),
    (2, 15, 18, '... flights to USA will be...weather temp is 73 degrees ...'),
    (2, 45, 47, '... flights to USA will be...weather temp is 73 degrees ...');
```